# Добавление блока по клику

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не получается добавить элемент. На вкладке "Add more products" при выборе товара он должен добавляться в основной блок но никак. Непосредственно когда основной блок виден новые элементы создаются а когда скрыт не получается. В чем дело и как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const addMore = document.querySelector('.more-title');
const formCheckbox = document.querySelector('.form-checkbox');
const btnContinue = document.querySelector('.form-btn');
const formInner = document.querySelector('.form-inner');
const btnError = document.querySelector('.form-error__btn');
const formBox = document.querySelector('.form-box');


addMore.addEventListener('click', function() {
  formInner.style.display = 'none';
  formCheckbox.style.display = 'block';
});
btnContinue.addEventListener('click', function() {
  formInner.style.display = 'block';
  formCheckbox.style.display = 'none';
});
btnError.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.form-error').style.display = 'none';
  formInner.style.display = 'block';
});

const addBtn = document.querySelector('.form-item');
const mainBlock = document.getElementById('#body');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const createBlock = document.createElement('div');
  createBlock.className = 'page-block';
  mainBlock.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', createBlock);
});
```

```css
.post-content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100vh;
}

.post-body {
  position: relative;
}

.post-body:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: url(../../images/bg.svg);
  top: -15px;
  right: -35px;
}

.post-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 440px;
  height: 535px;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #E2E7FF;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #E2E7FF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 35px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.form:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.form-box {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(225, 227, 238, 0.5);
  margin: 0 0 25px;
}

.form-box:nth-child(2) {
  border: none;
}

.form-box__item {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgba(225, 227, 238, 0.5);
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.form-box__item-keyword,
.form-box__item-link {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 4px;
}

#block2,
#block3,
#block4,
#block5 {
  display: none;
}

.form-title,
.form-box__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 134%;
  color: #1C154E;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.form-subtitle,
.form-box__item-subtitle {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: rgba(28, 21, 78, 0.8);
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.form-label,
.form-box__item-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 76%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #D0D3E2;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -o-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.form-box__item-label {
  top: 66%;
}

.form-email {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-email:focus+.form-label,
.form-email:focus+.form-box__item-label,
.form-email:valid+.form-label,
.form-email:valid+.form-box__item-label,
.form-box__item-keyword:focus+.form-label,
.form-box__item-keyword:focus+.form-box__item-label,
.form-box__item-keyword:valid+.form-label,
.form-box__item-keyword:valid+.form-box__item-label,
.form-box__item-link:focus+.form-label,
.form-box__item-link:focus+.form-box__item-label,
.form-box__item-link:valid+.form-label,
.form-box__item-link:valid+.form-box__item-label {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.form-email,
.form-box__item-keyword,
.form-box__item-link {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: rgba(28, 21, 78, 0.8);
}

.more-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #23C967;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.more-title__plus {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #23C967;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.more-subtitle {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #494471;
  margin: 0 0 19px;
}

.form-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.form-checkbox__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 134%;
  color: #1C154E;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.form-checkbox__subtitle {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: rgba(28, 21, 78, 0.8);
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.form-list {
  border: 1.5px solid #DDDFED;
  border-radius: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 23px;
}

.form-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #E1E3EE;
  padding: 11.5px 17px 10.5px 17px;
}

.form-item:nth-child(5) {
  border: none;
}

.form-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-item:hover {
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -o-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  background: #F4F5FA;
}

.form-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.form-checkbox:checked+.form-text:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.form-text {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}

.form-text span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: #23C967;
}

.form-text__item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 34px;
}

.form-text:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1.5px solid #E1E3EE;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
}

.form-text:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 5px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #23C967;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  -o-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

.form.send .form-button:before,
.form.send .form-button:after,
.form.send:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.form-btn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background: #23C967;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.form-button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #23C967;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.form-button:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: url(../../images/circle.svg);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: default;
  margin: auto auto;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.form-button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  background: #23C967;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.form.send .form-button:before {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.form-secure {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: #AFB4CC;
  margin: 11px 0 0 0;
}

.form-secure img {
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}

.form-error {
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 30px;
}

.form-error__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 134%;
  color: #1C154E;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.form-error__text {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: rgba(28, 21, 78, 0.8);
}

.form-error__img {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.form-error__btn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #EA717F;
}

.form-send {
  display: none;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 30px;
}

.form-send__title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 134%;
  color: #1C154E;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
}

.form-send__text {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 145%;
  color: rgba(28, 21, 78, 0.8);
}

.form-send__img {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.form-send__btn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #23C967;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-body">
  <div class="post-block">
    <form class="form" id="form" method="" action="#" name="feedback">
      <div class="form-inner">
        <div class="form-body" id="body">
          <div class="form-box">
            <div class="form-title">Info</div>
            <div class="form-subtitle">Enter your email address</div>
            <input class="form-email" id="email" type="text" name="email" required>
            <label class="form-label" for="email">team@checkforpatent.com</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-box">
            <div class="form-box__title">Product 1</div>
            <div class="form-box__item">
              <div class="form-box__item-subtitle">Enter main keyword for the product</div>
              <input class="form-box__item-keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" type="text" required>
              <label class="form-box__item-label" for="keyword">for example, sylicon wine cup</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-box__item">
              <div class="form-box__item-subtitle">Enter link to the similar product as a reference</div>
              <input class="form-box__item-link" id="link" name="link" type="text" required>
              <label class="form-box__item-label" for="link">https://...</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-add more">
            <div class="more-title">
              <p>Add more products</p>
              <div class="more-title__plus">+</div>
            </div>
            <div class="more-subtitle">
              <p>We offer discount up to 36% for multiple checks</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="form-button" type="submit">Submit and Pay <span>24.99</span> USD</button>
        <div class="form-secure"><img src="images/lock.svg" alt="">
          <p>Secure payment with Stripe</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-checkbox">
        <div class="form-checkbox__title">Adding more products</div>
        <div class="form-checkbox__subtitle">The more items you check, the better the price.</div>
        <ul class="form-list">
          <li class="form-item">
            <input class="form-checkbox" id="product5" type="radio" name="product" value="5">
            <label class="form-text" for="product5">
                          <div class="form-text__item">
                            <p>5 products for 80 usd / 16$ for each</p><span>You safe 36% on each patent check</span>
                          </div>
                        </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-item">
            <input class="form-checkbox" id="product4" type="radio" name="product" value="4">
            <label class="form-text" for="product4">
                          <div class="form-text__item">
                            <p>4 products for 72 usd / 18$ for each</p><span>You safe 28% on each patent check</span>
                          </div>
                        </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-item">
            <input class="form-checkbox" id="product3" type="radio" name="product" value="3">
            <label class="form-text" for="product3">
                          <div class="form-text__item">
                            <p>3 products for 60 usd / 20$ for each</p><span>You safe 20% on each patent check</span>
                          </div>
                        </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-item">
            <input class="form-checkbox" id="product2" type="radio" name="product" value="2">
            <label class="form-text" for="product2">
                          <div class="form-text__item">
                            <p>2 products for 44 usd / 22$ for each</p><span>You safe 12% on each patent check</span>
                          </div>
                        </label>
          </li>
          <li class="form-item">
            <input class="form-checkbox" id="product1" type="radio" name="product" value="1">
            <label class="form-text" for="product1">
                          <div class="form-text__item">
                            <p>1 product for 24.99 usd</p>
                          </div>
                        </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="form-btn">Continue</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-error">
        <div class="form-error__title">Your payment failed</div>
        <p class="form-error__text">Sorry, but we’ve having trouble processing your payment. You have been not charged for this transaction.</p>
        <div class="form-error__img"><img src="images/card2.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="form-error__btn">Try to pay again</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-send">
        <div class="form-send__title">Successfully payment</div>
        <p class="form-send__text">Your request has been accepted and will be processed within 24 working hours. We will send you a payment details and all information to your email.</p>
        <div class="form-send__img"><img src="images/card1.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="form-send__btn">Back</div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или везде используйте `querySelector`, или правильно пишите параметры.

```
const mainBlock = document.getElementById('body');
                                           ^
```

Comment: Блин.. Из пага скопировал как есть про решетку забыл. Спасибо

Comment: @СлаваГрачев Пожалуйста. Успехов.